# Why is the use of special characters in passwords considered to be a strong password?

Tags: html, passwords, password-encryption

Why should any strong password require special characters in it?

Some websites asks for the special characters to be entered as mandatory for creating the password.

Is there is any technical reason behind this?

Comment: [relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/936/)

Answer (score 2):

Of course. It's very long to explain and it exceeds my humble abilities, so you will need to read about the concept of [**Entropy in Information Theory**](https://web.archive.org/web/20181024163735/http://www.princeton.edu:80/~achaney/tmve/wiki100k/docs/Entropy_(information_theory).html). A simpler explanation from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password_strength#Human-generated_passwords):

**Human-generated passwords**

People are notoriously remiss at achieving sufficient entropy to produce satisfactory passwords. Some stage magicians exploit this inability for amusement, in a minor way, by divining supposed random choices (of numbers, say) made by audience members.

Thus, in one analysis of over 3 million eight-character passwords, the letter "e" was used over 1.5 million times, while the letter "f" was used only 250,000 times. A uniform distribution would have had each character being used about 900,000 times. The most common number used is "1", whereas the most common letters are a, e, o, and r.

Users rarely make full use of larger character sets in forming passwords. For example, hacking results obtained from a MySpace phishing scheme in 2006 revealed 34,000 passwords, of which only 8.3% used mixed case, numbers, and symbols.

Note that the full strength associated with using the entire ASCII character set (numerals, mixed case letters and special characters) is only achieved if each character in the password is chosen randomly from that set. Capitalizing a letter and adding one or two numbers and a special character to a password will not achieve the same strength. If the numbers and special character are added in predictable ways, say at the beginning and end of the password, they could even lower password strength compared to an all letter random password of the same length.
[NIST](http://www.nist.gov/) Special Publication 800-63

[image]

NIST Special Publication 800-63 of June 2004 suggests the following scheme to roughly estimate the entropy of human-generated passwords:[2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password_strength#Human-generated_passwords)

```
The entropy of the first character is four bits;
The entropy of the next seven characters are two bits per character;
The ninth through the twentieth character has 1.5 bits of entropy per character;
Characters 21 and above have one bit of entropy per character.
A "bonus" of six bits is added if both upper case letters and non-alphabetic characters are used.
A "bonus" of six bits is added for passwords of length 1 through 19 characters following an extensive dictionary check to ensure the password is not contained within a large dictionary. Passwords of 20 characters or more do not receive this bonus because it is assumed they are pass-phrases consisting of multiple dictionary words.
```

Using this scheme, an eight-character human-selected password without upper case letters and non-alphabetic characters is estimated to have 18 bits of entropy. The NIST publication concedes that at the time of development, little information was available on the real world selection of passwords.

[image]

Later research into human-selected password entropy using newly available real world data has demonstrated that the NIST scheme does not provide a valid metric for entropy estimation of human-selected passwords.
Usability and implementation considerations

Because national keyboard implementations vary, not all 94 ASCII printable characters can be used everywhere. This can present a problem to an international traveler who wished to log into remote system using a keyboard on a local computer. See keyboard layout. Many hand held devices, such as tablet computers and smart phones, require complex shift sequences to enter special characters.

Authentication programs vary in which characters they allow in passwords. Some do not recognize case differences (e.g., the upper-case "E" is considered equivalent to the lower-case "e"), others prohibit some of the other symbols. In the past few decades, systems have permitted more characters in passwords, but limitations still exist. Systems also vary in the maximum length of passwords allowed.

---

or, in Layman's terms: for each additional byte you're adding over alphanumerical options, you're making the passwords more complex and difficult to break.

More info [here](http://reusablesec.blogspot.com.ar/2010/10/new-paper-on-password-security-metrics.html)

Comment: how is my 20 char password with a special character named space has less entropy than 8 char ending with exclamation point. this all is so dumb people even start to think passwords are a bad idea and seek for alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

1) if you only use characters and digits, you may be using some word or numbers that can easily be guessed. Hackers have tools that repeatedly and quickly try all known words, and they try these before trying passwords with special characters

2) if you only use letters and digits the probability of guessing the character in any position is 1/62 (there are 62 possibilities).
If you use special chars ([there are 32 of them](https://kb.wisc.edu/page.php?id=4073)) the probability reduces to 1/94.
The total number of possible combinations that you can form if you type for example 8 characters, is 
a) if you don't use special chars: 62 ** 8 = 2.1834E+14
b) if you do use special chars: 94 ** 8 = 60.9569E+14

So there would be about 30 times more combinations using special chars, meaning, it would take about 30 times longer to crack a password with special chars than one without, given one uses 8 characters in the password

Answer (score 1):

In fact, this is a stupid and outdated requirement. Like most people, I rely on my password manager to suggest secure passwords, and mine (at least, from a very small company based in Cupertino) finds that very long random alphanumeric passwords are plenty secure. If it's 20 random characters, the security difference between a 62 character (26 letters, regular and cap, plus 10 numbers) and 72 character keyboard is trivial.

But there's more: if a website won't accept the long, random alphanumeric passwords that the Apple's Keychain generates, then I, poor human, will have to generate one instead, and remember it. That means I am either going to use a shorter, much less random password, or (even worse), I'm going to use my 'standard' password because it's simply too much trouble to keep track of 100s of unique passwords, which is what most of us need nowadays.

I wish that the whole 'special character' requirement would go away, or else that Apple would put one in each of its otherwise plenty secure long random passwords, because it's a total pain now.

Comment: I highly doubt that 'most people' rely on a password manager, but I do appreciate your strong opinion on this matter.

Answer (score 0):

The main technical reason behind it is it's difficult to guess, for increasing password security it's a good practice. When anyone try to exploit, at first he tries to do it using dictionary attack, if you use special character, you are safe from this issue. For this reason, few organizations make a password policy which include this rule for better security.